# how to do vector (vertical) sum in scala with Spark1.6

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD `(long, vector)`. I want to do sum over all the vectors. How to achieve it in spark 1.6?

For example, input data is like

```
 (1,[0.1,0.2,0.7])
 (2,[0.2,0.4,0.4])
```

It then produces results like
     [0.3,0.6,1.1]

regardless of the first value in `long`

Comment: Vectors are always dense ?

Comment: And what are the exact types here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an RDD[Long, Vector] like this:

```
val myRdd = sc.parallelize(List((1l, Vectors.dense(0.1, 0.2, 0.7)),(2l, Vectors.dense(0.2, 0.4, 0.4))))
```

You can reduce the values (vectors) in order to get the sum:

```
 val res = myRdd
  .values
  .reduce {case (a:(Vector), b:(Vector)) => 
    Vectors.dense((a.toArray, b.toArray).zipped.map(_ + _))}
```

I get the following result with a floating point error:

> [0.30000000000000004,0.6000000000000001,1.1]

source: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28232829/addition-of-two-rddmllib-linalg-vectors?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: May I know what "zipped" does?

Comment: I can reproduce the given solution. However, when performing on my RDD, it shows error "type mismatch, expected:(vector, vector)=>vector, actual:(vector,vector)=> indexed seq[any]".

Comment: my data type is RDD([long, verctor])

Comment: are your vectors member of scala.collection.immutable.Vector? I suspect we're not using the same collection type.

Comment: just checked, the vector I used is from org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg, i.e., `sealed trait Vector extends Serializable`

Comment: is this post related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28232829/addition-of-two-rddmllib-linalg-vectors  @vzamboni. I think the addition operation should use the one work for the vector in Spark, right?

Comment: thanks! follow the insights, I just implemented a similar solution. '{case (a:(Vector), b:(Vector)) => Vectors.dense((a.toArray, b.toArray)
        .zipped
        .map(_ + _))}'

Comment: great! glad it helped! i edit the answer with the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer [spark example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a26e3ed5e414d0a350cfe65dd511b154868b9f1d/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/mllib/LDAExample.scala),about:

```
 val model = pipeline.fit(df)
val documents = model.transform(df)
  .select("features")
  .rdd
  .map { case Row(features: MLVector) => Vectors.fromML(features) }
  .zipWithIndex()
  .map(_.swap)
(documents,
  model.stages(2).asInstanceOf[CountVectorizerModel].vocabulary, 
  //vocabulary
  documents.map(_._2.numActives).sum().toLong)
  //total token count
```