# Why can I only retrieve Array[Float] word vectors but have to pass mllib.linalg.Vector to w2v model?

Tags: apache-spark, word2vec

I am having trained a word vector model and now I'd like to do some operations on those vectors.

Currently I try to figure out how to e.g. add up some vectors like below and then get some synonyms from the resulting vector. The problem is that `model.findSynonyms(org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector, Int)` is making problems since I only get `Array[Float]` from my `model`. This is why I try to create a `DenseVector` which itself now needs `Array[Double]` and the chaos is perfect - but take a look yourself:

```scala
val model = Word2VecModel.load(sc, modelPath)
val headVector = model.getVectors.head
val synonyms = model.findSynonyms("computer", 10)
var aVec : Array[Float] = new Array(headVector._2.length)

for((synonym, cosineSimilarity) <- synonyms) {

  println(s"  $synonym $cosineSimilarity")

  // Returns Array[Float] (unfortunately)
  val bVec = model.getVectors.get(synonym).get
  val zipped = aVec zip bVec

  aVec = zipped.map(t => t._1 + t._2)
  println(util.Arrays.toString(aVec))
}

println(util.Arrays.toString(aVec))

// aVec is Array[Float] instead of Array[Double]
// or even better: something that implements org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
val v : DenseVector = new DenseVector(aVec)

model.findSynonyms(aVec, 10)
```

This does not compile since aVec is `Array[Float]` instead of `Array[Double]`. This is because I can only get `Array[Float]` from my `model`. So either I am doing it completely wrong or that's a major issue of the API..

Is there another way to do this or will I have to convert all my vectors between those two types? Why am I not getting something from my `model` that implements `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector`?

---

I also try this as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28232829/addition-of-two-rddmllib-linalg-vectors)

```
val v1 = new org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector(aVec)

for((synonym, cosineSimilarity) <- synonyms) {

  val v2 = new DenseVector(model.transform(synonym).toArray)

  val s = Vectors.dense((v1 + v2).toArray)
}
```

but I get a compilation error that `v1 + v2` results in `Array[Char]` and not `Array[Double]`..

Answer (score 0):

Your second example will not work because your `synonym` is a String - which gets converted to an Array of Characters:

```
model.transform(synonym).toArray
```

So the `v1 + v2` performs an addition of a float to a character array- which is a `Array[Char]` as you discovered.

As for the original question: yes you will need to convert from `Array[Float]` to `Array[Double]`